# API management with odata backend, would $metadata work

Tags: azure-api-management

How would I define the template for odata, is this supported with api management? thanks!

e.g.

- metadata endpoint
- odata filters, $top, $filter, $expand etc

Could someone point me a few examples please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just create a normal operation with collection URI. $top, $filter, and $expand - are just query parameters, you can add them to operation definition as well. Shouldn't be any different from registering any other operation with query parameters, really, as APIM does not have any special handling for OData.